Safari issues with input type=email and multiple attribute
In my experience, when viewing an HTML input field of type "email" with the "multiple" attribute present, Safari shows a blank input, whereas Chrome and FF show the field as expected.
Is this a known bug with Safari? Googling turns up very little for me.
This pen has two inputs, the first is a multiple-email input, the second is just a single value. I expect to see the addresses when viewing the field in Safari, just as I do in Chrome and FF. Instead, it is blank.
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="customer_email">A standard multiple-email input field</label><br>
    <input type="email" size="75" name="customer_email" id="customer_email" value="example@example.com,testing@testing.com,foo@bar.com" placeholder="" multiple>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="single_email">A standard single-email input field</label><br>
    <input type="email" size="75" name="single_email" id="single_email" value="single@example.com" placeholder="">
    </div>
</form>

https://codepen.io/abmg/pen/poBBxOG
Chrome and FF show as expected:

Whereas Safari shows the multiple input as blank:


that seems like a bad ux to use that. why not just have multiple textboxes?

@DanielA.White It's being used in the admin area of a WordPress site by a plugin the client is beholden to. So altering the form to use different fields is not in scope here. But more importantly, UX aside, the field is valid HTML and constructed properly, but doesn't display properly on all versions of Safari.

It certainly looks like a bug to me, and it's still there in Sonoma 14.6.1.  I have found that a workaround is to use JavaScript to change the type attribute to 'text', which causes the value to be shown, and then to change it back to 'email'.
